# ElasticSearch Parse Error

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am attempting to read JSON Data from a Network Port Scan and store these results in an ElasticSearch Index as a document. However, whenever I try to do this, I get a `MapperParsingException` error on the `scan output` results. In my mapping, I even tried to change the analysis to `not_analyzed` and `no`, but the error doesnt go away. Then, I figured that ES might be trying to interpret certain values as `date` values and attempted to set `date_format` to `0` or `none`. That led to a dead-end as well, with the mapping throwing an `Unsupported` option exception.

I have a dump of the values that I want to index in ElasticSearch here:

```
{
    "protocol": "tcp",
    "service": "ssh",
    "state": "open",
    "script_out": [
        {
            "output": "\n  1024 de:4e:50:33:cd:f6:8a:d0:c4:5a:e9:7d:1e:7b:13:12 (DSA)\nssh-dss 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\n  2048 94:5f:86:77:81:39:2e:03:e0:42:d8:7d:10:a5:60:f0 (RSA)\nssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDV9BKj+QSavAr4UcDaCoHADVIaMOpcI5/hx/X9CRLDTxmB/WvEiL42tziMZEx7ipHT28/hl4HOwK64eXZuK75JMrMDutCZ2gmvRmvFKl6mAVbUEOlVkMGZeNJxATCZyWQyrZ6wA9E2ns5+id6l9C8we+bdq39cIR/e+yR8Ht8sfaigDi0gcW67GrHDI/oIgTQ79l+T/xAqCVrtQxqn/6pCuaCWQUVCxgOPXmJPbsd+g+oqZtm0aEjIJvcDJocMkZ2qMMlgMPeJBN27FCTKB80UUbV57iHXHzZF+cD7v+Jlw0fmyMapMkkPH+aabOUy7Kkbty1mucrFxaisLsckEf47",
            "elements": {
                "null": [
                    {
                        "type": "ssh-dss",
                        "bits": "1024",
                        "key": "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",
                        "fingerprint": "de4e5033cdf68ad0c45ae97d1e7b1312"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "ssh-rsa",
                        "bits": "2048",
                        "key": "AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDV9BKj+QSavAr4UcDaCoHADVIaMOpcI5/hx/X9CRLDTxmB/WvEiL42tziMZEx7ipHT28/hl4HOwK64eXZuK75JMrMDutCZ2gmvRmvFKl6mAVbUEOlVkMGZeNJxATCZyWQyrZ6wA9E2ns5+id6l9C8we+bdq39cIR/e+yR8Ht8sfaigDi0gcW67GrHDI/oIgTQ79l+T/xAqCVrtQxqn/6pCuaCWQUVCxgOPXmJPbsd+g+oqZtm0aEjIJvcDJocMkZ2qMMlgMPeJBN27FCTKB80UUbV57iHXHzZF+cD7v+Jlw0fmyMapMkkPH+aabOUy7Kkbty1mucrFxaisLsckEf47",
                        "fingerprint": "945f867781392e03e042d87d10a560f0"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "id": "ssh-hostkey"
        }
    ],
    "banner": "product: OpenSSH version: 6.2 extrainfo: protocol 2.0",
    "port": "22"
},
```

**Update**
I am able to index the content in the "output" key. However, the error appears when I try and index the content in the "elements" key

**Update 2**
There's a possibility that there's something wrong with my mapping. This is the python code that I am using for the mapping.

```
"scan_info": {
                        "properties": {
                            "protocol": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "index": "analyzed"
                                },
                            "service": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "index": "analyzed"
                                },
                            "state": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "index": "not_analyzed"
                                },
                            "banner": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "index": "analyzed"
                                },
                            "port": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "index": "not_analyzed"
                                },
                            "script_out": { #is this the problem??
                                "type": "object",
                                "dynamic": True                                    
                            }

                        }
              }
```

**I am drawing a blank here. What do I need to do?**

Comment: I think `None` should have some quotes around it: `{'Supported Methods': {None: ['GET', 'HEAD'`.

Comment: @AndreiStefan - That doesn't seem to be the problem. I replaced the "None" values with another value. But the `TransportError(400, u'mapper_parsing_exception', u'failed to parse [scan_results.scan_info.script_out]')` still persists. I have pasted my new dictionary above...

Comment: I tried the exact json in the question and it works for me... I can index it.

Comment: @AndreiStefan - I find that I can only index the stuff in the `output` key and not the `elements` key. Ill give it another shot and check. Ill post my mapping. Maybe there's something wrong there....

Comment: What ES version is this? What's the complete error message? When do you get the error (indexing time?)? How do you index (what's the command you use)?

Comment: Also, get the mapping from ES, not from the python code: `GET index_name/_mapping` (I'm not sure what's the index name).